# Android app for different screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm an italian guy and i'm developing an android app for a course that i'm attending at Information and Communication Technologies university.
This is my question: following android philosophy, it is right to create 12 folders for different values of hight and width (in dpi) in android?

I mean:

```
values-ldpi
values-mdpi
values-hdpi
values-xhdpi
values-small-ldpi
...
...
...
values-xlarge-hdpi
values-xlarge-xhdpi
```

I can't use `"match_parent"` or `"wrap_content"` everywhere, so for some components i have to specify the size in dpi.

Comment: I wrote dpi (dots per inch) but i mean dp (density independent)

Comment: I don't know whether other people will agree with me but I've used these two libraries by Intuit - [SSP](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) and [SDP](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) and it works in every screen size without entering into this mess. Check them out.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, but you can get a whole way by simply putting up your XML layouts smartly, using Fragments and thinking of a design that allows the use of some relative position descriptions.

Comment: what do you mean for "relative position description"? Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: You can create a layout, with per example a button in the middle, or left/right against its parent. Things like that are easily achieved in XML. With a lot of 'floating' views that aren't really having a position easily as that you'll have a hard time making it correct for every possible screen

Answer (score 0):

There is not a generic rule that can work always.
In some cases you could have to use `values-land`, `values-v14`, `values-large-land-v14`, `values-sw720dp`....depends on the app you want to achieve.

Don't forget **`values-xxhdpi`**

Comment: I forget to say that the app will run only in portrait-mode

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is certainly the most exhaustive and thorough. It isn't necessarily "right" as you say though.

Ideally you would be able to create values/layouts/drawables for every possible combination of screen size/density. In the real world, it is more common to focus on a particular subset.

For example, you can have a look at the most commonly used screen densities [here](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens) (updated periodically).

There are particular drawbacks to being exhaustive, including large .apk sizes if you are dealing with drawables, and as such you can scale back your approach and focus elsewhere, or release multiple .apk's for your application.

There is an in-depth article on **Supporting  Multiple Screens** on Android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) which is well worth a read.

Comment: I read that article many times but i think it doesn't give a concrete way on how to support ALL types of screens.. :(

Comment: Like I said, to support every single screen (there are over 2200 devices) would be very exhaustive, and it is better to focus on a subset. For example, the most popular groups are currently normal/hdpi and normal/xhdpi. Focus there first, then bring in support for less popular combinations once you've got the popular groups looking optimal

Comment: Thank for your answer, i have another question: I have two tablets, both of 7" but the first is hdpi and the second mdpi. In my layout i have a button with specified dimensions 250dp*100dp (width/height). Why in the first tablet the system scales the dimensions and hold the right proportions and in the second it doesn't??? I mean, if i run the application on my Nexus S (4") and on the first tablet, everything seems equal, but if i do the sime and i compare the layout of my nexus with the second tablet they are totally different.

Comment: The mdpi tablet will have larger pixels to fill the same space as the hdpi tablet. Android therefore uses the mdpi graphics which should compensate for this, and scales any graphics from other densities that it does not have. This is why you are seeing the issue. you can put drawables you don't want to change into the  res/drawable-nodpi folder